# How to make the third person character picking item to pick up the item even if the item is a bit far?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded the animation from mixamo.com

The picking up is working fine. I have pick up animation and I added event and the character is picking up the item smooth.

The problem is that I have to put the item (cube) very close to the character even a bit on the player right foot so the animation with the hand will get to the item.

Is there any way to make that the item will be a bit far from the foot and yet the picking up animation to be accurate? because if I move the cube a bit far from the character foot it will look like it's picking up nothing because the hand will not reach the cube.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickupItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform cube;
    public Transform destinationTransform;

    private bool startChild = false;
    private float timer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        timer = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (startChild)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            cube.position = Vector3.Lerp(cube.position, destinationTransform.position, timer);

            if (timer >= 1.0f)
            {
                cube.parent = destinationTransform;
                cube.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
                startChild = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void PickupEvent()
    {
        startChild = true;
    }
}
```

The character with the animation event in the inspector:

[image: animation event]